# Transactions sent with skip preflight = false on devnet fail

Tags: web3.js

Whenever I send a transaction on Devnet using
`web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction()`, the transaction fails with the following error:

```
Error: 400 Bad Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"invalid 2nd argument: config object was missing 'skipPreflight' element"}}
    at ClientBrowser.callServer`
```

If i manually set `skipPreflight: true`, the transaction succeeds.

This same code was working a couple days ago, and now I'm seeing failures across the board. Using version `1.66.2` of `web3.js`, anyone else seeing the same issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like it belongs on the Solana GitHub as a bug report. Post it here! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/new